# Find a sequence of differentiable functions $\{f_n\}$ on $[0,1]$ such that $f_n \to 0$ uniformly, but $\{f_n'(1/2)\}$ does not converge to $0$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, uniform-convergence

> Find a sequence of differentiable functions $\{f_n\}$ on $[0,1]$ such that $f_n \to 0$ uniformly, but $\{f_n'(1/2)\}$ does not converge to $0$.

I have tried to find an example which follows above condition, but failed to approach. Please help me!

Comment: Get some kind of collection of $\sin$ functions to wobble faster and faster while getting lower and lower in height as $n$ increases.

Comment: Alternatively, you can "smoothen" a step function so as to make it differentiable.

Answer (score 0):

Consider, for example, the fucntion $$f_n(x)=\frac{sin(2n\pi x)}{\sqrt n}$$
Clearly $f_n \to 0$ uniformly but $\{f_n'(1/2)\}$ diverges.